# jQuery UI Modal Dialog window without overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Ive been experimenting with the jQuery UI Modal Dialog, it seems very nice, however not quite what I need - is there a possibility to open the dialog without having the gray overlay that disables the background? Something like this:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html
(but telerik are expensive, for now I need something open source)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and you should have not face such issue as this is the default behavior of the dialog:

> modalType: Boolean
>
> Default: false
>
> If set to true, the dialog will have modal behavior; other items on
>   the page will be disabled, i.e., cannot be interacted with. Modal
>   dialogs create an overlay below the dialog but above other page
>   elements.

Try setting [modalType](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal) to false.

EDIT:

The modalType is renamed to [modal](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal) only in jQuery UI 1.10.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mantain the modal functionality you can change the background overlaying style by customizing the `.ui-widget-overlay` class into the jqueryui css or using themeroller too, section `Modal Screen for overlays`.

If you don't want the modal feature just change the `modalType` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is this:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ modal: true }); // with the overaly

$( ".selector" ).dialog({ }); //without the overlay
```